# is it possible to install stuff to dosbox

Tags: iso-image, ms-dos, dosbox

I ***legally*** downloaded an ISO of space hulk and a copy of `dosbox 0.74-3`.

I mounted the ISO, opened it up in `dos` and then in an attempt to play it, I tried to install it.

The whole thing just freezes like this.

[image: screen shot of whats happening]

I can't tell if it just takes forever to install because dos is slow or if its either:

A) doesn't know what I'm telling it to do..

...or

B) doesn't have any hard rive space it knows to install to.

Could you please tell me how I can play this?

Could you also tell me what to do if dos just doesn't accept any further keyboard input.

Comment: Can you try a DOS virtual machine? I have one of these.  When DOS freezes, 95% of the time all you can do is turn it off.

Comment: no, i wanted to use oracle but becauuse my laptops screen is broken im using my tv as a monitor with a hdmi, and i have to go into bios to get oracle working... but when i go into bios the screen goes black (i think because when in bios your computer cant recognize external devices so the tv as a monitor doesnt work).

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please tell me how I can play this?

**Running From CD/DVD**

Assuming the game is mounted in DOSBox under drive `D:`, navigate the to the `HULK\HRD_DIR` directory and run `MAIN.EXE` with the appropriate options:

*ex. DOSBox*

```
C:\> D:

D:\> cd hulk

D:\HULK> cd hrd_dir

D:\HULK\HRD_DIR> main sb d e 220 7 1 -1
```

The second option to `main` (ex. `d`) should always match whatever drive letter is being used in DOSBox for the Space Hulk CD-ROM.

---

**Hard Drive Installation**

1. Copy the files and folders from the ISO (i.e. everything in your screenshot) to somewhere acceptable on your hard drive.
2. In DOSBox, run the [mount](https://www.dosbox.com/wiki/MOUNT) command with the path to the copied files e.g.:

   *ex. DOSBox*

   ```
   mount e "C:\path\to\the\game"
   ```

   In this case, `e` is the DOSBox virtual drive letter you wish to access these files with (you can pick any letter already not in use/mounted, often `E:` through `Y:`).

   To avoid having to run this command every time you start DOSBox, you can add it to your DOSBox configuration file under the `[autoexec]` section e.g.:

   *ex. dosbox-0.74-3.conf*

   ```
   ...

   [ipx]
   # ipx: Enable ipx over UDP/IP emulation.

   ipx=false

   [autoexec]
   # Lines in this section will be run at startup.
   # You can put your MOUNT lines here.

   # These are just examples
   MOUNT D D:\ -t cdrom
   MOUNT C C:\some\path\DOSGames -freesize 1024

   # Space Hulk
   MOUNT E "C:\path\to\the\game"

   # Another example
   C:
   ```

   The DOSBox configuration file can usually be found under `C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Local\DOSBox`.
3. Assuming you have run ex. `mount e "C:\path\to\the\game"` in DOSBox (or have added it to your DOSBox configuration file and restarted DOSBox), navigate to to the `HULK\HRD_DIR` directory in the main DOSBox window and run `INSTALL.EXE`:

   *ex. DOSBox*

   ```
   C:\> e:

   E:\> cd hulk

   E:\HULK> cd hrd_dir

   E:\HULK\HRD_DIR> install
   ```
4. In the main the installation menu, pick your preferred language and press `Enter` to continue to the next screen.
5. Use the down arrow key to select the *Sound FX* option (this defaults to `No sound`) and press `Enter` again to continue to the *Sound FX* options screen. Use the up and down arrow keys to select a sound device (the plain `SoundBlaster` device should work without issue, though you can try others if you like).
6. Finally, press `Enter` to be taken back to the main options screen (from Step 5, above). Use the down arrow key to select `Continue` and press `Enter` twice to write a `HULK.BAT` file to disk.
7. Outside of DOSBox, navigate to ex. `C:\path\to\the\game\HULK\HRD_DIR` and open `HULK.BAT` with a text editor (e.g. Notepad). It should look something like the following:

   *ex. HULK.BAT*

   ```
   main sb D E 220 7 1 -1
   ```

   `main` refers to the `MAIN.EXE` file in the same folder and the rest of the items after it are options for when it is run:

   - Sound Device
   - CD-ROM drive letter
   - Language
   - Address
   - IRQ
   - DMA
   - DRQ

   Change the second option (i.e the CD-ROM drive letter ex. `D`) to whatever drive letter you assigned to the game files in DOSBox in Step 2 (e.g. `E:`) and save the file:

   *ex. HULK.BAT (modified)*

   ```
   main sb E E 220 7 1 -1
   ```
8. You can now use `HULK.BAT` in this directory (`HULK\HRD_DIR`) to start the game.
9. If you wish to make things a little easier (so you don't need to navigate to `HULK\HRD_DIR` and run `HULK.BAT` manually), you can make e.g. a second `HULK.BAT` file at the root of `C:\path\to\the\game` (so ex. `C:\path\to\the\game\HULK.BAT`) with the following code:

   *ex. HULK.BAT (version 2)*

   ```
   CD .\HULK\HRD_DIR
   HULK.BAT
   ```

   This `HULK.BAT` can then be run directly in DOSBox to start the game ex.:

   ```
   E:\> HULK.BAT
   ```